# How to multiply columns by first column in DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have applied a performance rank per participant in my survey. 
I now want to apply their respective rank on their question response (+1 to -1)
I have 2 data frames

> df1

```
SetAScore   rank_A
689964  0.90    1.000000
689966  0.65    0.771845
689967  0.65    0.771845
689968  0.55    0.286408
689970  0.55    0.286408
```

> df2

```
Participant response-1-quantised response-101-quantised 

689964 1 -1
689966 1 -1
```

The end result I am seeking is:

Participant response-1-quantised response-101-quantised

689964 1 -1 *(edited)*
689966 0.771845 -0.771845 *(edited)*

Maintaining the structure of df2, which has 120 question response columns and 113 rows (1 row per participant).

I see the "key" being the 'Participant' number

I have tried to also bring the 'rank_A' column into df2 and perform a simple multiply but to no success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated for my MSc

(sorry about the format, I'm a noob) I can share images if easier. Thanks!

EDIT ----

I think I have solved it with @joe's help (thanks Joe!)

```
for col in b_test:
    result_df[col] = [a*b for a,b in zip(set_rank['rank_A'].values.tolist(),b_test[col].values.tolist())]
    result_df[col] = [a*b for a,b in zip(set_rank['rank_A'].values.tolist(),b_test[col].values.tolist())]
```

This seems to have worked as I had to loop through n columns

Comment: `df.mul(df.iloc[:,0], axis=0)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.isin()` to filter your `df1` `Participant` column by the `Participant` column from your `df2`.

Then do the multiplication by the remaining columns.

```
#to filter
df1 = df1.loc[df1['Participant'].isin(df2['Participant'].values.tolist())]

#do the multiplication
result_df = pd.DataFrame()
result_df['Participant'] = df1['Participant'].values.tolist()
result_df['Response Positive'] = [a*b for a,b in zip(df1['Score'].values.tolist(),df2['Positive Multiplier'].values.tolist())]
result_df['Response Negative'] = [a*b for a,b in zip(df1['Score'].values.tolist(),df2['Negative Multiplier'].values.tolist())]
```

Your `new_df` now will have the result you wanted.

Take note that the `Positive Multiplier` is the column with `1` in it and the `Negative Multiplier` is the one with `-1`. Change that in the code depending on the column name of your original dataframe, I just used that to clarify which column to use. I hope that won't confuse you.

Conversely, the `Score` is the column with the `0.90` as one of the values in your sample above.

Hope this helps. Let me know if you got it :))

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. In the df2 I have truncated it's actually a lot larger than that and the questions span to 120. The participants' responses are either +1 (true) or -1 (false) . I think if I set the df2[positive/negative' multiplier] that restricts the calculation to that column? Perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: So your solution seems to work - thank you! :) However, just to my last comment if I want to iterate over 'undefined' amount of columns, what would you suggest?  Participant Response Positive Response Negative
0 689964 0.90 -0.90
1 689966 0.65 -0.65
2 689967 0.65 -0.65
3 689968 0.55 0.55

Comment: Sorry one more thing... :) I would like to maintain the column headers of df2 in the new df so essentially I have the participant #, question-#-quantised, ... As the column headers of the new df. Sorry that wasn't clear before

Comment: Hello,  if df2 is larger than df1,  use the `Participant` in df1 and do the filtering on df2. It would get all the columns of your df2 into the new df if you follow the code. What do you mean by 'underfined' number? Is it volume? In that case you have to loop it through then creat a df per new range of positive and negative vals. I'll try to show the code, it's just I'm on mobile right now. And oh, don't forget to upvote post if it helped you. Thanks :))

Comment: Hi, So when I say df2 is larger I mean I have 120 `response` columns. But I have the same amount of participants in both df. Sorry, by the undefined number I mean, the amount of `responses` will vary. So I have a set of 120 participant response but I will be creating two sample sets out of that, therefore, I am thinking I need to have the flexibility of the number of columns - I am thinking a look could be best for this? Thanks! And Yes I upvoted but SO says thanks but my upvote won't show until I get some kudos or ranking :-/

Comment: I think it got it `for col in b_test:
    result_df[col] = [a*b for a,b in zip(set_rank['rank_A'].values.tolist(),b_test[col].values.tolist())]
    result_df[col] = [a*b for a,b in zip(set_rank['rank_A'].values.tolist(),b_test[col].values.tolist())]`